# Is it compulsory to use ext oscillator in designing arduino circuit?

Tags: oscillator, atmega328p

I am designing a circuit for arduino. I will be using `Atmega328p`, and will connect few male header for pin access and 6 male headers for programming (MOSI,MISO,SCK,RST,Vcc,GND). So is it compulsory to use ext oscillator. I know MCU can also work using int oscillator but not sure that while programming it through `USBasp` it will work or not. I heard somewhere that while programming it using `USBasp` ext osciallator is required. So ext oscillator is required or not.?

Comment: what problem you are getting in connecting ext oscillator to your circuit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default clock source for the atmega328p is the internal RC oscillator @ 8MHz with the CKDIV8 fuse programmed.  See page 28 [here](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8271-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega48a-48pa-88a-88pa-168a-168pa-328-328p_datasheet_complete.pdf).

You can absolutely program the part using the internal RC oscillator.  After all the part ships with this default configuration.  Assuming that you want to program the part using the arduino IDE and have everything behave as expected you will need to change some settings in you arduino boards.txt file so that the internal clock source is selected (as you know the arduino boards that use the atmega328 ship with an external oscillator and the boards.txt file by default instructs the part to use the external oscillator) and then burn the boot loader.  In boards.txt you'll have to modify the fuses to select the proper clock source.  One easy solution is to modify the uno board settings since that board uses the same chip.  Copy/paste all the uno settings so that you have a new board (call it yourUno or something) entry in the file.  The Uno board has the following settings:

```
uno.bootloader.low_fuses=0xff
uno.bootloader.high_fuses=0xde
uno.build.f_cpu=16000000L
```

You'll want to modify that to:

```
yourUno.bootloader.low_fuses=0xe2
yourUno.bootloader.high_fuses=0xda
yourUno.build.f_cpu=8000000L
```

This should select the internal 8MHz RC as your clock source.  Note that per the comments below there are other ways of doing this if you're OK with a 1 MHz clock.

Comment: Note that the fuse settings are only used when `Burn Bootloader` is selected in the Arduino IDE. If you intend to never use this option then there is no need to change that part of the configuration. Also note that the default bootloader for the Uno assumes a 16MHz clock; you will need to modify and rebuild it if you want it to operate at 8MHz.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yeah good point, but I'm assuming he's going to program the part using the arduino IDE/library.  If he doesn't burn the bootloader then things like delay() won't behave as expected.

Comment: yes I need to upload the bootloader first. So you mean to say while uploading bootloader, I need to change `uno.build.f_cpu=16000000L` to `Uno.build.f_cpu=8000000L` and then I can design my circuit without oscilator. and during programming i'll choose the internal oscillator. Am I right.?

Comment: The bootloader is not at all required in order to use Arduino libraries on the chip.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that's true, but if he tries, for example, delay(100) it won't delay 100 mS as expected.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams bootloader not required.??? So you mean to say I can directly upload my arduino code to atmega328p and these functions like `delay()` `Serial.begin()` will work properly.?

Comment: They will work just fine if the `f_cpu` parameter matches the clock speed of the device, regardless of bootloader.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I didn't knew that. Earlier I uploaded the bootloader and then programmed my atmega328p. I'll try this one also.!

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that's true, but the default clock is 1 MHz.  If he wants anything different isn't easier to just modify one file in one place and be done?  Otherwise he has to #define the f_cpu and modify the fuses.

Comment: @user46573544 I think the easiest thing for you to do is create a new entry in boards.txt with the modifications I suggested.  If you burn the boot loader with your new board entry selected in the IDE then everything should work fine.

Comment: Setting `f_cpu` makes sense. The fuse settings are not required. The bootloader itself is certainly never required (unless you *want* to be able to program it via UART).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams you have really confused me with this bootloader thing. Lets say I have a new atmega328p IC, fuses and everything is set properly so programming it will work fine.? I mean all those funcitons of arduino will work.?(I am not sure) and to make it program via UART I thought we need another IC atmega8.

Comment: @Doov I got your point. I'll modify the boards.txt file and then burn the bootloader and later program it. But  Ignacio is saying no bootloader required.?

Comment: @user46573544: The ATmega8U2/16U2 on the Uno acts as a USB-UART bridge. If you supply your own bridge (or don't program via UART) then there is no need for it.

Comment: @user46573544 Ignacio is correct.  You do not *need* to use the bootloader, however if you want to modify the clock source so that it's not 1 MHz I think the easiest thing for you to do is modify the boards.txt and burn the bootloader.  So long as you have your own USB-UART bridge then you can subsequently program it over UART.

Comment: If I can directly upload my arduino code to fresh atmega328p, then its great. I didnt knew that. Thanks Doov & Ignacio

Comment: @user46573544 yes -- you *can* directly program the part from the arduino IDE.  It will not work as expected though!  The IDE assumes you're operating your part at 16 MHz -- you aren't!!  The default clock is 1 MHz so *you need to modify something so that everything works as expected*.  The solution I provided will utilize an 8 MHz internal clock.  If you are OK with 1 MHz then you can use Ignacio's solution.

Comment: The solution provided will allow the Arduino IDE to change the clock, but there is no requirement to use the IDE for that. It is easy to use avrdude to reprogram fuses without getting the IDE involved.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I understand that, but given the OP's question/comments I think this is the most user friendly way to modify the fuses and move on.  Using avrdude works fine, but is in my opinion less user friendly.

Answer (score 2):

An external oscillator is only required during programming if the fuses are programmed to require one during normal operation. There is no requirement for it to be a crystal though; it is possible to inject a clock at least 3 times faster than the programming clock via XTAL1 if one is required. See the "Memory Programming" section, "Serial Downloading" subsection of the ATmega328P datasheet for details.